# Send one more parameter from serialize()

Tags: ajax, jquery

Into the "data" line of my AJAX code, I would like to send one more parameter (called "action") from serialize(). The 'data' line would look like this (obviously it doesn't work) :

```
    $('.input_inscription').blur(function(){
        var myInput = $(this);

        $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "my_url.php",
                    data:myInput.serialize()+"&action='input_control'",
                    success: function(data){
                       if (data.a == true){
                            $(".inscription_form_ctrl").text( data.b );                                 
                       }else{
                            $(".inscription_form_ctrl").text( data.b );
                       }
                    }
        });             

    });
```

Ps: I serialize a input field, not a form ! So i need to add the "action" parameter "manually" (it can't be a hidden input for example).

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a little more of your code to get a clearer idea of what you are doing?

Anyway,
If you do wish to pass the data through the url, you might as well append the &action="input_control" to the form action attribute if you are using a form, like so

```
<form action="next.php?action='input_control'" method="POST" >
```

Comment: Hi, I serialize a input field, not a form ! So i need to add the "action" parameter "manually" (so it can't be a hidden input for example).